# Can i create constraints, from within a uiview's initialization, to its superview

Tags: swift, uiview, initialization

Ive created many views, which is not a problem. However i have a lot of changes constraints code in VC which need refactoring.

QUESTION:

How (if possible) can i set up constraints inside the init method of the subView itself so i can refactor the code out of the VC.

I cant think of another way to frame my question for google, so here is what ive got:

VC

```
    func addCheckView() {
        let checkView = CheckView()
        checkView.frame = self.view.frame
        view.insertSubview(checkView, aboveSubview: mapView)
    }
```

```
import UIKit

class CheckView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }


    private func commonInit() {
        backgroundColor = .blue
//        addSubview(self)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        let margins = layoutMarginsGuide
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
//        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Ive tried a huge number of variations, but to keep this short and readable (and as i think the solution is quite simple) i will leave it at this.

Obviously, i could simply do something like this and pass the touches through:

```
private func commonInit() {
let view = CheckView()
// add constraints here, etc.
}
```

This works, however is this not just adding a subview within a subview? This seems inelegant and verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot constrain a view to its superview until it *has* a superview. But `init` happens before there is a superview, so you can't move your constraint code into it. Instead, in your UIView subclass, implement `didMoveToSuperview()`. Now for the first time `self.superview` is not `nil` and the view can constrain itself to its superview.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have searched everywhere on google, and i even knew that  the superview was the problem, just not how to solve it! The first time didMoveToSuperview() has been suggested.

Comment: on a slightly unrelated note: is this good practice? to put layout code in the subview itself? Or should i just subclass the entire view of the viewcontroller and put all of the constraints in there (if that makes sense)

Comment: How you architect encapsulation depends on questions of reusability and knowledge (e.g., who needs to know and be responsible for how a view is constrained). No hard and fast rules can be given.

Comment: Ok, ill keep that in mind when implementing, will have a google for best practice with encapsulation. Thanks again